# the Rambam was hard of understanding

Tags: history, rambam, historical-figures

Someone told me that the Rambam when he was young was hard of understanding

Is there a reputable source confirming this?
How can I find it?

What I found so far.

> לא הצטיין בשום תכונה מיוחדת. לא הייתה לו נטייה ללימודים, וכל מה שלמד- לא נקלט בראשו. **קשה הבנה** היה וקשה תפיסה

From http://cms.education.gov.il/NR/rdonlyres/F7CA73FE-1416-45D3-B4C4-6AB75566EC85/123043/chomer_reka.doc

Comment: For the benefit of readers, it should be noted that the quote is (a) directly preceded by "כך מספרת **האגדה**" ("as the story/legend goes"), (b) it's from a story who's source is given there as "מאיר אוריין, _המורה לדורות_, הוצאת מוסד הרב קוק, ירושלים , עמ' 27", and (c) that it is brought as part of a collection of such stories about the Rambam (and not as part of his biography).

Comment: @TamirEvan thank you it is page 25(27) here https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?148851

Comment: Can you define "reputable source"?

Comment: @Yishai the more trustworthy (in your opinion) the source the better

Comment: [This](https://www.inn.co.il/Forum/Forum.aspx/t112780) quotes it from Seder Hadorot (צ"א תתכז, apparently supposed to be ד"א תתכז?), but I looked there and didn't see it

Comment: @ba because of you i found it also in first person ואני משה הצעיר הייתי קשה הבנה מאוד so it might be a letter from the Rambam

Comment: For some reason this is a claim that's popular to make about gedolim. It might be true sometimes, but I think the vast majority of the time it's not.

Comment: @Daniel who else?  (other then the Rambam) (this information is very confidence boosting)

Comment: @ba it is there and he also brings, a source 9 lines from the bottom right colom http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=229

Comment: It's unclear to me that this question is on-topic as about Judaism.

Comment: What's interesting is that in a sense Rambam's "hard of understanding" behavior seems to have been passed onto many of his own writings. Many complained that when he wrote *Yad Hachazaka* he rarely cites sources. Many had a huge issue with that, as his own work was hard for others to understand.

Comment: @ba can you help find who is he quoting? Then it will be a full answer (I will b"n except)

Comment: I found what seems to be the earliest written source (since he quotes it from "an old man" rather than a specific book), but I couldn't find where the first person account might have come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source for this story seems to be Shalshelet Hakabbala (p. 104 [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&st=&pgnum=113)). He says he heard it from an old man who saw it written in an old book.

The relevant part of the story is:

> וזה הרמב"ם היה קשה ההבנה מאד ומעט רצון היה לו בלמוד
>
> This Rambam was very hard of understanding, and had little desire to learn.

The story is quoted almost verbatim in [Seder Hadorot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=229) (source found by hazoriz).

The book [Hamore Ladorot](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?148851) by Me'ir Oryan (source located by Tamir Evan) quotes the legend, but judges that the true core of the story is probably limited to the part of the story about the Rambam going to learn from Rabbi Yosef Ibn Migash, implying that in his view the line about the Rambam being hard of understanding might have been an embellishment.

Comment: It's worth noting that Seder Hadorot is generally not considered a reputable source of historical information. Indeed, the whole section on Rambam seems to be replete with errors. See here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80153/3388

Comment: @Chaim If you can find a better source for the statement, you can post it. I never wrote that the claim was true, and if anything, implied the opposite.