# What does Judaism have to say about ADHD?

Tags: psych-mentalhealth

I have been diagnosed with AD/HD. I have often struggled in school and social interations. Even relationships have often not been smooth for me. What sources does Judaism have about AD/HD or learning difficulties in general. Cited sources are preferred so I can read them for myself.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Daniel. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Now I'm reading a bit about ADHD on Wikipedia, and it says that it was recognised as a disorder since the 19th century, so I have doubts that rabbonim discussed this in detail before this date. There were children, who needed more time and attention, which was perfectly normal...

Comment: I myself have many learning difficulties (which I overcome). this might be what you are looking for https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90750/5120

Comment: @Kazi I wouldn't say today. Malbim discussed bipolar. Reb Yisroel Salanter discussed the subconscious. The 19th century is a good place to look in rabbinic literature for mental health.

Comment: @user6591 I don't say it didn't exist, just it wasn't regarded as an _illness._

Comment: @Kazi I was responding to: "and it says that it was recognised as a disorder since the 19th century, so I have doubts that rabbonim discussed this in detail before this date"

Comment: I may be mistaken on who it is, but I think the Minchas Osher has a lot of health and psychology related Teshuvos (assuming I have the right person, he was working as the chief Posek for Shaarei Tzedek Hospital, so he addressed a lot of these questions). That might be a good place to start. I believe he was also interviwed on the Headlines podcast, if you want to hear some of his ideas.

Comment: I don't believe that the specific classifications of psychological illnesses that we have given "formal" labels to were known or discussed much prior to Freud. There are a few discussed in the Talmud. In particular, a *shoteh* (generally translated as an "imbecile") is mentioned constantly throughout Talmudic literature. The exact parameters of a *shoteh* is somewhat complex. However, the *shoteh* is generally exempt from performing mitzvoth, because he has almost no mental skills to understand what he is doing.

Comment: Please coordinate your title with the question body. Are you focusing specifically on ADHD or any learning disorder?

Comment: http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/on-education-genius-and-adhd/

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/880377/rabbi-elli-fischer/did-abaye-have-adhd-/

Comment: Thank you everyone for getting back to me. I apologies for the extreme long delay in getting back to you. Been struggling with a lot of mental health issues lately.

Comment: So I can only think of needing help with my ADHD. I feel that if that can be treated my other conditions caused by the ADHD can also be improved.